# How can I use Sticky effect on a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-scrollview

I'm trying to combine Roman Nurik and Nick Butcher's 'Sticky' effect (https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt) in a ListView, with no success.

My problem is the following: I need to design a profile screen layout that has a first section (basically an image), then a menu bar (I want it to be 'Sticky') and then a ListView with the user uploaded photos.

I can't combine the `ObservableScrollView` with a ListView inside, but I need both (`ObservableScrollView` for the Sticky and ListView for the view recycling and optimization - I need to load images in the ListView items).

The idea is when the user scroll the screen, the first image (the user 'banner') scrolls and goes out the screen, the menu bar sticks to the topa and keep then, and the ListView keeps scrolling until the last photo.

Any ideas? Do you know any library or trick to achieve this effect?

Regards,